# Updating MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am trying to use PHP to update MySQL database and I am testing it with an HTML form.

I intend to use this in an android app so that is where the values will be taken from but currently I am just testing with a HTML form to test the PHP code. When I am testing with the HTML form the appropriate data is not being updated currently.

What is wrong with my code that causes this?

PHP code:

```
/*
* Following code will create a new product row
* All player details are read from HTTP Post Request
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['PlayerID']) && isset($_POST['Score']) && isset($_POST['LastHolePlayed'])&&     
isset($_POST['Overall'])) {

$playerid = $_POST['PlayerID'];
$score = $_POST['Score'];
$lastholeplayed = $_POST['LastHolePlayed'];
$overall = $_POST['Overall'];

// include db connect class
require('db_connection.php');



// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `week1` SET Score = `$score`, LastHolePlayed = `$lastholeplayed`, 

Overall` = $overall` WHERE PlayerID = `$playerid`");


// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Player successfully added.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

html code:

```
<form action="http://localhost/realdeal/updateplayer.php" method="POST">
PlayerID <input type="text" id='PlayerID' name='PlayerID'><br/><br/>
Score <input type="text" id='Score' name='Score'><br/><br/>
LastHolePlayed <input type="text" id='LastHolePlayed' name='LastHolePlayed'><br/><br/>
Overall <input type="text" id='Overall' name='Overall'><br/><br/>

    &nbsp;  <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Column names - backquotes, values - single quotes

Comment: Are you sure column names are correct?

Comment: I believe so each input value is to be representative of a column in mysql database correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query delimiters need to be corrected:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `week1` SET Score = '$score', `LastHolePlayed` = '$lastholeplayed', `Overall` = '$overall' WHERE `PlayerID` = '$playerid'");
```

Notice the backticks (`) around column and table names and single quotes (') around the values.

Also, when you are debugging a query, always check for MySQL errors:

```
$result mysql_query(...) or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error() );
```

Finally, you should know that your query leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. Always clean your input data before including it in a query.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I included the debugging query and it is saying that I am getting an error - '` WHERE `PlayerID` = `6`' at line 1

Comment: @user2243017 You are missing a single-quote before the value of 6 (`'$overall'`)

Comment: Thanks that solved that problem though, I think the statement is not doing what I want, I am trying to to update the row where PlayerID is equal to the PlayerID that has been entered where as it seems to be using the column names here.

Comment: Check the value of `$playerid` and confirm that it matches a row in your table. Perhaps the input data is not what you expect. Also, try echoing your query so that you can run it manually for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your help it was to do with having the `$overall` which refers to a column instead of '$overall' which refers to a row

Answer (score 2):

change your query to:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `week1` SET `Score` = '$score', `LastHolePlayed` = '$lastholeplayed', `Overall` = '$overall' WHERE `PlayerID` = '$playerid'");
```

Comment: Thanks I changed it to this but the database is still not being updated . I am getting the output - {"success":0,"message":"An error occurred."}

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is wrong. You can write as stated above or you can directly write the statement without any apostrophe symbol as - 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE week1 SET Score=$score, LastHolePlayed=$lastholeplayed, Overall=$overall WHERE PlayerID=$playerid");

Moreover, can you explain what do you mean by "appropriate data is not being updated". It would be more clear if you give/state the error you are getting.